# Enter multiple variables into an R function

Tags: r, function

I want to enter multiple variables into an R function, and I want to enter them all in the `table1()` function ==> something like this line `tab<-table1(~ var1+var2+ var3+...+varN|group, data=data)`

```
library(table1)
dataset<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),group=c("gp1","gp2","gp1","gp2","gp1","gp2","gp1","gp2"),
                 col1=c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0),col2=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),col3=c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0))


print.f <- function(data,var1,...,group){
  tab<-table1(~ var1+...|group, data=data)
  tab
}

print.f(data,var1,var2,var3,group=group)

print.f(dataset,col1,col2,col3)
```

[image]

If I will have for example a dataset that contains more than 3 columns and I want to see their output, how could I enter all of them?

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried? What's the question?

Comment: @camile, how could I enter the number of variables that I want into table1()?
I did an edit to the post to make my question more clear

Comment: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#fun-dot-dot-dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the formula as a character vector, convert to formula class and run table1.  In the examples we show several ways of creating the same output using print.f or using table1 directly.

```
print.f <- function(data, ..., group) {
  v <- paste(c(...), collapse = "+")
  if (!missing(group)) v <- paste(v, "|", group)
  fo <- as.formula(paste("~", v))
  table1(fo, data = data)
}

library(table1)

print.f(dataset, "col1", "col2", "col3", group = "group")

print.f(dataset, c("col1", "col2", "col3"), group = "group")
print.f(dataset, grep("col", names(dataset), value = TRUE), group = "group")
print.f(dataset, names(dataset)[2:4], group = "group")

print.f(dataset[-1], ".", group = "group")
print.f(dataset, ". - ID", group = "group")

table1(~ . | group, dataset[-1])
table1(~ . - ID | group, dataset)
```

Comment: Very nifty! For my part, I was intrigued by a language-oriented approach (rather than one with `paste`d strings), and in the process, I came up with the `op_literal()` function as seen [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70267929). Do you know if a similar function already exists? I wasn't able to track anything down, so I had to make my own.

Comment: @Greg, `reformulate(c("a", "b", "c"))[[2]]` gives the same output as ``op_literal(`+`, a, b, c)``

Comment: Awesome!  Is there a function that extends to any binary operator whatsoever, for an arbitrarily large set of operands?  Or only with `+` for formulas?

Comment: I don't think so. reformulate is intended to be used with regression formulas.

Comment: Good to know! If I can make `op_literal()` play nicely with packaged operands like ```dplyr::`%>%` ```, which are fully qualified yet which cannot be coerced to a `symbol`, then I might actually have something here!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that manipulates language rather than strings. You and others might also find `op_literal()` useful in the future.

## Solution

### Helper: `op_literal()`

This helper function `op_literal()` actually manipulates the R language itself to repetitively use a binary operator like [`+`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Arithmetic.html) across **many** operands...even though a binary operator typically accepts only *two* operands. Calling `` op_literal(`+`, w, x, y, z) `` will actually generate this [`expression`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/expression.html) here: `w + x + y + z`.

```
# Helper function to arbitrarily repeat a binary operation (like '+').
op_literal <- function(op, ...) {
    # Capture the operator as a symbol.
    op_sym <- rlang::ensym(op)
    # Count the operands.
    n_dots <- rlang::dots_n(...)
    
    # Recursive case: a binary operator cannot handle this many arguments.
    if(n_dots > 2) {
        # Split off the final operand.
        dots <- rlang::exprs(...)
        dots_last <- dots[[n_dots]]
        dots <- dots[-n_dots]
        
        # Perform recursion for the remaining operands.
        op_left <- rlang::inject(op_literal(
            op = !!op_sym,
            ... = !!!dots
        ))
        
        # Assemble recursive results into the full operation.
        substitute(op(op_left, dots_last))
    }
    # Base case: the binary operator can handle 2(-) arguments.
    else {
        substitute(op(...))
    }
}
```

#### Note

Since `op_literal()` generates an `expression`, you still need to [`eval`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/eval.html)uate it if you want the *result*:

```
op_exp <- op_literal(`+`, 1, 2, 3, 4)
op_exp
#> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4

eval(op_exp)
#> [1] 10
```

---

### Custom Function: `print.f()`

Next, this custom `print.f()` then leverages `op_literal()` to assemble the formula:

```
# Your custom 'print.f()' function.
print.f <- function(data, var1, ..., group) {
    # Capture the core variables as symbols.
    group_var <- rlang::ensym(group)
    other_vars <- rlang::ensym(var1)
    
    # Count the additional variables.
    n_dots <- rlang::dots_n(...)
    
    # Append those other variables if they exist.
    if(n_dots > 0) {
        other_vars <- rlang::inject(op_literal(op = `+`, !!other_vars, ...))
    }
    
    # Assemble the formula.
    formula_exp <- rlang::inject(~ !!other_vars | !!group_var)
    
    # Generate the table according to that formula.
    table1::table1(
        formula_exp,
        data = data
    )
}
```

## Result

Given your `dataset` reproduced here

```
dataset <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
    group = c("gp1", "gp2", "gp1", "gp2", "gp1", "gp2", "gp1", "gp2"),
    col1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    col2 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
    col3 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
)
```

your call to `print.f()`

```
print.f(dataset, col1, col2, col3, group = group)
```

should yield the following visualization:
[image: 4]

## Note

As it stands, you have defined the `group` parameter at the *end* of your function header. This means that if you try calling `print.f()` like so

```
print.f(data = dataset, var = col1, col2, col3, group)
```

then **you will get an error**: without the `group =`  specification, that final variable gets lumped together with `col2` and `col3`, all under the `...` umbrella. This will generate a bad formula:

```
~ col1 + col2 + col3 + group |
```

To avoid the pain of having to type out `group =`  every time, you can simply relocate it before the `...`, like so:

```
print.f <- function(data, group, var1, ...) {
  #                       ^^^^^
```

Once you've done so, the following call will work as you intended:

```
print.f(dataset, group, col1, col2, col3)
```